# Technology vs. technologies

Tags: grammatical-number

What is the better sentence? It looks like **technologies** is the better word since there are many of them. However, most of the similar sentences on the Internet use the singular form **technology**

> Samsung is the leader in display technology

or

> Samsung is the leader in display technologies

or

> Samsung is the leader in display technology innovation

Comment: 3. is absolutely horrible to English ears! It just means "you can safely ignore this, because it is a badly worded advertisement". Claiming to be the leader is bad enough, but packing "innovation" in as well is too much.

Comment: I agree that it sounds a bit awkward

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to ODO : 
[Technology](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/technology): is both countable and uncountable.

> - ( mass noun) The application of scientific knowledge for practical purposes, especially in industry:
>     advances in computer technology,;
> - [count noun]: recycling technologies. ( specific technologies).
>
>   - These new technologies can be useful, if we apply them to practical problems.
>       The lead times for developing new technologies in the nuclear industry are very long.
>   - New technologies in medicine are crucial and will have an enormous impact.
>   - Machinery and devices developed from scientific knowledge:
>       it will reduce the industry’s ability to spend money on new technology

As for your examples, if you want yo stress the different technologies available in the display sector, the plural form is more appropriate.

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=display%20technology%2Cdisplay%20technologies%20&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdisplay%20technology%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdisplay%20technologies%3B%2Cc0): display technology vs display technologies.

Source: www.oxforddictionaries.com

Answer (score 4):

Truly a matter of opinion and taste as both are correct depending on how one chooses to lump together discrete technologies.

My choice is to let context dictate.  If the surrounding context touches on specific discrete technologies, plural is the way to go.  If the surrounding context is instead focused on Samsung in the display industry, perhaps competing with others, then I choose the singular.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that "technology" is too specific to encompass more than one type of technology to the average reader.

If you said something like "The technologies of the biomedical and microcomputer fields are merging to create exciting possibilities for.... (etc.)" then you have two different types of technology.

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't agree less.

Which do you prefer:

1. Information technologies can support multilingualization
2. Information technology can support multilingualization

(2) does not refer to just one technology but everything contained in IT. No need to mention technologies. It grinds on my ears. It's for people who love: Emergent, enhance, and all these pseudo scientific-sounding platitudes and clichés.